# CS-cart - assigning variables into config file

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3, cs-cart

In my `CS-cart 4` **PHP** project I have a `Smarty 3` (tpl) view file..

There I have defined one JavaScript function like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

            api_key: 'JSABFISAG472IB4'

  ....
```

I am very new at using it, so I wanted to ask/check if this hardcoded API key could be added on a config? **Where** and how? Still have a trouble finding similar examples online..

Checked: [CS-cart documentation](https://docs.cs-cart.com/latest/developer_guide/getting_started/configuring_cscart.html)

Checked: [Smarty Help Forum](https://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=80982)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a config.php or config.local.php file? if not create one and add it there `define('KEY','1234567890');` And call it like this in tpl {$smarty.const.KEY}